# VBA code to count number of rows (in filtered data) & sum a relevant column in filtered source file

Tags: vba, count, rows

I would like to get help on VBA codes to:

- count the number of rows (which could be filtered) from a source file which I have opened and reported the number in a master file.
- have the sum of a relevant column in the source file and report the value in a master file.

The reason for these questions is to make sure that the input source file has been completely copied into the master file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim endRow as integer
Range("a1").select
selection.End(xlDown).Select
endRow = activecell.row
```

This is assuming that all fields in that column will have values.
This also works with xlToRight and xlToLeft as long as there are values in each cell.

Comment: Hi Tamara, how do I get it to count the number of filtered rows and report the number

Answer (score 0):

To count the non-blank non-hidden cells in Column A of Worksheet `Sheet1`, you can use this code:

```
WorksheetFunctions.Subtotal(103, Sheet1.Columns(1))
```

To do so in a Cell is very similar:

```
=SUBTOTAL(103, Sheet1!$A:$A)
```

(Of course, this *will* include your header row)

(`SUBTOTAL(3, Sheet1!A:A)` is the same as `COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)` - using `103` instead is what makes it ignore the hidden/filtered-out rows)